# Maven clean install only works with sudo on a certain project?

Tags: maven, npm, osx-yosemite, aem

Without getting into the details of my project. I am wondering if this is a common issue. without sudo I get NPM errors. NPM was installed correctly. On MAC Yosemite?

error below

```
C00427@C17PN92CG8WN ~/s/c/ui>
mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ACS.org CQ5 --> PARENT --> UI 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ ui ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.180 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-12T09:59:46-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project ui: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/org.acs.cq-code-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
C00427@C17PN92CG8WN ~/s/c/ui>
```

If I use sudo it works perfectly fine

```
C00427@C17PN92CG8WN ~/s/c/ui> sudo mvn clean install
Password:
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ACS.org CQ5 --> PARENT --> UI 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ ui ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.25:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) @ ui ---
[INFO] Node v5.0.0 is already installed.
[INFO] Found NPM version 3.3.9
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.25:npm (npm install) @ ui ---
[INFO] Running 'npm install --color=false' in /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui
[ERROR] npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON ui@0.0.0 No repository field.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.25:gulp (gulp build) @ ui ---
[INFO] Running 'gulp.js --no-color' in /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui
[INFO] [10:02:23] Using gulpfile ~/sites/cq5/ui/gulpfile.js
[INFO] [10:02:23] Starting 'default'...
[INFO] [10:02:23] Starting 'coffee'...
[INFO] [10:02:23] Finished 'default' after 11 ms
[INFO] [10:02:24] Finished 'coffee' after 657 ms
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ ui ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 6 resources to META-INF
[INFO] Copying 2093 resources to jcr_root
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:copy-dependencies (copy-bundles) @ ui ---
[INFO] Copying jackson-databind-2.5.1.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/jackson-databind-2.5.1.jar
[INFO] Copying org.apache.sling.models.api-1.1.0.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/org.apache.sling.models.api-1.1.0.jar
[INFO] Copying guice-1.0.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/guice-1.0.jar
[INFO] Copying commons-lang3-3.0.1.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/commons-lang3-3.0.1.jar
[INFO] Copying com.springsource.org.apache.commons.codec-1.3.0.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.codec-1.3.0.jar
[INFO] Copying com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar
[INFO] Copying com.springsource.org.aopalliance-1.0.0.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/com.springsource.org.aopalliance-1.0.0.jar
[INFO] Copying com.springsource.org.cyberneko.html-1.9.13.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/com.springsource.org.cyberneko.html-1.9.13.jar
[INFO] Copying com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient-3.1.0.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient-3.1.0.jar
[INFO] Copying jackson-annotations-2.5.1.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/jackson-annotations-2.5.1.jar
[INFO] Copying com.springsource.org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient-4.1.1.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/com.springsource.org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient-4.1.1.jar
[INFO] Copying groovy-all-2.3.8.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/groovy-all-2.3.8.jar
[INFO] Copying com.springsource.org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore-4.1.1.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/com.springsource.org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore-4.1.1.jar
[INFO] Copying commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
[INFO] Copying commons-logging-1.1.1.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
[INFO] Copying jackson-core-2.5.1.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/jackson-core-2.5.1.jar
[INFO] Copying com.springsource.org.apache.xmlcommons-1.3.4.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/com.springsource.org.apache.xmlcommons-1.3.4.jar
[INFO] Copying io.wcm.cq5.sling.models-1.0.0.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/io.wcm.cq5.sling.models-1.0.0.jar
[INFO] Copying com.springsource.org.openid4java-0.9.6.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/com.springsource.org.openid4java-0.9.6.jar
[INFO] Copying com.springsource.org.apache.xerces-2.9.1.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/com.springsource.org.apache.xerces-2.9.1.jar
[INFO] Copying org.apache.sling.models.impl-1.1.0.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/org.apache.sling.models.impl-1.1.0.jar
[INFO] Copying com.springsource.org.apache.httpcomponents.httpmime-4.1.1.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/com.springsource.org.apache.httpcomponents.httpmime-4.1.1.jar
[INFO] Copying com.springsource.org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient-cache-4.1.1.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/com.springsource.org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient-cache-4.1.1.jar
[INFO] Copying ehcache-2.7.0.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/ehcache-2.7.0.jar
[INFO] Copying com.springsource.org.apache.xml.resolver-1.2.0.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/com.springsource.org.apache.xml.resolver-1.2.0.jar
[INFO] Copying com.springsource.com.google.inject-2.0.0.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/com.springsource.com.google.inject-2.0.0.jar
[INFO] Copying com.springsource.net.spy.memcached-2.5.0.jar to /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/classes/jcr_root/apps/acs/install/com.springsource.net.spy.memcached-2.5.0.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ ui ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ ui ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ ui ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ ui ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- replacer:1.5.0:replace (default) @ ui ---
[INFO] Replacement run on 1 file.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ ui ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/org.acs.cq-code-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ ui ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/org.acs.cq-code-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /var/root/.m2/repository/org/acs/cq/ui/1.0-SNAPSHOT/ui-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/pom.xml to /var/root/.m2/repository/org/acs/cq/ui/1.0-SNAPSHOT/ui-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] --- cq-deploy-plugin:0.0.4:install-package (install-package-author) @ ui ---
[INFO] execute
[INFO] Connecting to server: http://localhost:4502
[INFO] Connecting with user: admin
[INFO] Deleting package at path: org.acs.cq-code-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[WARNING] Delete failed: no package
[WARNING] Delete failed with jar, trying with zip.
[INFO] Deleting package at path: org.acs.cq-code-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
[INFO] Delete succeeded
[INFO] Uploading package /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/target/org.acs.cq-code-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to path: org.acs.cq-code-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Upload succeeded
[INFO] Package upload successful
[INFO] Installing package at path: org.acs.cq-code-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[WARNING] Installation failed: no package
[WARNING] Installation failed with jar, trying with zip.
[INFO] Installing package at path: org.acs.cq-code-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
[INFO] Installation succeeded
[INFO] Package installation successful
[INFO] Package Upload/Installation Completed Successfully
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16.859 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-12T10:02:36-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/514M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: check instalation directory of maven. if it is in root than you need sudo. Install maven in Users/"your_user" and it should work fine.

Comment: Seems permission issues @ /Users/C00427/sites/cq5/ui/

Comment: @VivekDhiman i know its a permission issue but how do I fix it?

Comment: @Akosha mvn is install here /usr/share/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/mvn  how do i move it

Comment: It's complaining it cannot delete the jar file so my guess is the jar is in use by another process.  Is your project running thus locking the jar file?

Comment: you need to do fresh install. and remove existing one. maybe it will help.

Comment: write answer to your own question how you resloved it so in future somebody have similar issue know how to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue was resolved by reinstalling NPM. As many times as I tried to uninstall and install NPM, i never deleted hidden files that were left over inside `usr/` folder.

I don't really understand why sudo worked. But the issue was resolved.

Comment: NPM ? I thought you are having a problem with maven ?please help me understand

Comment: this was months ago and i dont really remember anymore